# is convertion to DTO like this ok or it is a bad practice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have Entity that has list of another entities inside. Same for DTO, dto object with a list of another dto.

I need to convert Entity to DTO with the list inside.

Here how it looks with streams ( a bit messy, don't know if it is ok to use ):

```
public List<RestaurantDto> getAll() {
    List<Restaurant> restaurantList = restaurantRepository.findAll();
    return restaurantList.stream()
            .map(restaurant -> new RestaurantDto(restaurant.getName(), restaurant.getAddress(),
                    restaurant.getDishes().stream()
                            .map(dish -> new DishDto(dish.getId(), dish.getName(), dish.getPrice(), dish.getRestaurant()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Here is my DTO

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RestaurantDto {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private List<DishDto> dishes;
    private int votes;

    public RestaurantDto(String name, String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public RestaurantDto(String name, String address, List<DishDto> dishes) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.dishes = dishes;
    }

    public void addDish(DishDto dishDto) {
        dishes.add(dishDto);
    }
    public List getDeishes() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(dishes);
    }
}
```

And DTO that is in List

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class DishDto {
    private int id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @Digits(integer = 12, fraction = 2)
    private double price;
    private String restaurantName;
    private String restaurantAddress;
    @Digits(integer = 12, fraction = 0)
    private int restaurantId;

public DishDto(int id, String name, double price, int restaurantId) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.restaurantId = restaurantId;
}

public DishDto(int id, String name, double price, Restaurant restaurant) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.restaurantName = restaurant.getName();
    this.restaurantAddress = restaurant.getAddress();
    this.restaurantId = restaurant.getId();
}
```

}

I do appreciate your help a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, retrieving the whole entity and then converting it to DTOs in order to have fewer fields can be considered as an anti-pattern.

You should use projections if you want to retrieve less fields from the entity.

Bringing all the fields to the memory and then using just couple of them is not a good idea.

Take a look at projections. The following resources may help:

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Comment: I had to use DTO's as entities were connected with OneToMany and ManyToOne associations and both of them had to be serialized and I got StackOverflowError.
JsonBackReference only lets you serialize one of the Entities ( fields are omitted during serialization from one of the sides ), so it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @Henry_Muller . . . You're probably doing it the wrong way. The StackOverflowError has nothing to do with the concept of projection in this scenario. Bringing the whole entity to the memory if you need to use only some fields is an anti-pattern and must be avoided. Projections can easily solve this problem without any additional conversion. . .

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for the guide, i didn't know about the feature. But it seems like it is useless when DTO has another DTO ( two repositories are needed ). I haven't found any example when it was used in that scenario. Seems like it only works for the basic stuff.
I hope my point of view is wrong.